# Using setTime() or setNull() in PreparedStatement depending on user input

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am making a filtered search in my JAVA application and PostgreSQL database.

I have following PostgreSQL query for selecting data about flights:

```
String query =  "SELECT flight.flight_id, route.from_location, route.to_location, flight.base_cost, flight.departure_date, flight.departure_time, flight.arrival_date, flight.arrival_time, aircraft.manufacturer, aircraft.seats " +
                "FROM flight " +
                "INNER JOIN route ON flight.route_id = route.route_id " +
                "INNER JOIN aircraft ON flight.aircraft_id = aircraft.aircraft_id " +
                "WHERE " +
                "(from_location = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN from_location ELSE ? END) AND " +
                "(to_location = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN to_location ELSE ? END) AND " +
                "(base_cost = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN base_cost ELSE ? END) AND " +
                "(departure_date = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN departure_date ELSE ? END) AND " +
                "(departure_time = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN departure_time ELSE ? END) AND " +
                "(arrival_date = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN arrival_date ELSE ? END) AND " +
                "(arrival_time = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN arrival_time ELSE ? END)";
```

Then I have a Java code like this:

```
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    try {
                if (!showFromTxtField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    prepStatement.setString(1, showFromTxtField.getText());
                    prepStatement.setString(2, showFromTxtField.getText());
                } else {
                    prepStatement.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR );
                    prepStatement.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR );
                }
                if (!showToTxtField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    prepStatement.setString(3, showToTxtField.getText());
                    prepStatement.setString(4, showToTxtField.getText());
                } else {
                    prepStatement.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR );
                    prepStatement.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR );
                }
                if (!showCostTxtField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    prepStatement.setFloat(5, Float.parseFloat(showCostTxtField.getText()));
                    prepStatement.setFloat(6, Float.parseFloat(showCostTxtField.getText()));
                } else {
                    prepStatement.setNull(5, java.sql.Types.FLOAT );
                    prepStatement.setNull(6, java.sql.Types.FLOAT);
                }
                LocalDate depDate = showDepDateDatePicker.getValue();
                if (depDate != null) {
                    prepStatement.setDate(7, Date.valueOf(depDate));
                    prepStatement.setDate(8, Date.valueOf(depDate));
                } else {
                    prepStatement.setNull(7, java.sql.Types.DATE );
                    prepStatement.setNull(8, java.sql.Types.DATE);
                }
                if (!showDepTimeTxtField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    try {
                        Time timeValue = new Time(formatter.parse(showDepTimeTxtField.getText()).getTime());
                        prepStatement.setTime(9, timeValue);
                        prepStatement.setTime(10, timeValue);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    prepStatement.setNull(9, java.sql.Types.TIME );
                    prepStatement.setNull(10, java.sql.Types.TIME );
                }
                LocalDate arrDate = showArrDatePicker.getValue();
                if (arrDate != null) {
                    prepStatement.setDate(11, Date.valueOf(arrDate));
                    prepStatement.setDate(12, Date.valueOf(arrDate));
                } else {
                    prepStatement.setNull(11, java.sql.Types.DATE );
                    prepStatement.setNull(12, java.sql.Types.DATE);
                }
                if (!showArrTimeTxtField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    try {
                        Time timeValue = new Time(formatter.parse(showArrTimeTxtField.getText()).getTime());
                        prepStatement.setTime(13, timeValue);
                        prepStatement.setTime(14, timeValue);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    prepStatement.setNull(13, java.sql.Types.TIME );
                    prepStatement.setNull(14, java.sql.Types.TIME );
                }

                rs = prepStatement.executeQuery();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So the point is to return only those flights, which met the criteria from text fields. If any of text fields is left empty then query should return all flights for that particular criteria, but filtered with other non-empty criteria.

I have an error at parameter $9.
When I convert `String` (eg. "18:00:00") entered into `showDepTimeTxtField`, to `java.sql.Time` object which I can use as input parameter for `prepStatement` method `setTime()` my query should return only flights (which had met other criteria) with `departure_time` same as time entered into text field. If text field is left empty with no `String` input, my query should return flights with whatever `departure_time` they have, from my database.

My problem is, that when I run my code I get a following error:
**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $9** which I get wheter I fill `departureTimeTxtField` with string or leave it empty so the parameter `departure_time` should be set to NULL and my query should return flights with all `departure_time`'s.

So I assume I have a problem with `setTime()` method argument `timeValue` and conversion from `String` to `java.sql.Time`.

How to make a proper conversion so I'll get rid of that ERROR?

**EDIT: SQL query and Java source code updated.**

Comment: What happens when you just assume the parameter is not null and execute `SELECT * FROM flights WHERE departure_time = ?` ? That's what I would do anyway (and use `select * from flights` if your parameter is null).

Comment: Hello sir. When I executed the code only with `SELECT * FROM flights WHERE departure_time = ?` it has worked, but my query is much more complex. I made an edit please have a look.

Comment: I would dynamically generate a SQL query rather than using a single query that handle all the optional parameters. Using QueryDSL, for example.

Comment: You should only have to use `setNull` for primitive types, for all non-primitive types you should be able to just use `setXXX(null)`. Check if you're using the latest PostgreSQL driver, if you are, then file a bug report as using `setTime(null)` should work for a compliant JDBC driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to work around the issue by using `COALESCE()` instead of `CASE WHEN ...`:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM flights WHERE departure_time = COALESCE(?, departure_time)";
```

Comment: Thank you SIR, you've saved my life... Also can you please explain why my query is not working with CASE WHEN approach?

Comment: *"can you please explain why my query is not working with CASE WHEN approach?"* - I can offer a guess, but that's all it is. If the `CASE WHEN`  approach worked for you in other places and only failed for `java.sql.Time` values then it *could* be a bug, and you might want to consider filing a ticket, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: @PeterBabinec: I guess it has something to do with how the data type of an expression is evaluated. Probably `case` and `coalesce()` work differently here.  I have seen similar problems with Oracle's `nvl()` vs. `case`

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated because of invalid `CASE` syntax in SQL (and not because of time format), have a look at `CASE` syntax [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html).

Also, from the example, it seems you are trying to fetch all the flights whose departure time is either null or time present in text field, in this case, I would recommend the following approach:

```
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement prepStatement = null;
if (!departureTimeTxtField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Time timeValue = new Time(formatter.parse(departureTimeTxtField.getText()).getTime());
    prepStatement  = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM flights WHERE departure_time = ?");
    prepStatement.setTime(1, timeValue);
}else{
    prepStatement  = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM flights WHERE departure_time IS NULL");
}
rs = prepStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Hi. There shouldnt be problem with query syntax. I use this "CASE" approach in another class but without JOIN and only with Integer and Float datatypes and all is working. This error has occurred only when I've started to mess with Time. Also I've updated my question, because my query is more difficult and there would be A LOT of if-else statements with approach you've posted.